# How do I access the created database on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, sql, database, sqlite

Is it possible to read an .SQL file that is created from an SQLite database when you run the app?

I would like to have the entire database (with the data that is inserted from the app).
This doesn't get inserted in the .sqlite database, only in the .sql file (the apps database which is the copy of the .sqlite database).

How can I read this entire database? (With the changes made from using the app?).

Thanks!
Tjekkles

Comment: Once you run the app your database will copy into the simulator location. so you can get the updated database from your simulator destination.

Comment: Yes indeed, thats the question, How do I read the .SQL file? When I open it with a normal texteditor tool it gives me weird signs, and normally I read such a file with that.

Comment: You can read (open) _sql_ file in **Firefox** using the tool **SQLite Manager**.

Comment: The SQLite Manager only reads .sqlite files, it doesn't seem to read the .sql file.

Comment: It does it, didn't know it could do that, last time I did it I had an error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is solved, as Sisu said I opened it in SQLite Manager.

If Sisu answers this I can mark as the good answer.

Tjeu